# Need to extract specific word from text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to run data cleaning process in python and one of the column which has too many rows is as follows:

```
|Website            |
|:------------------|
|m.google.com       |
|uk.search.yahoo    |
|us.search.yahoo.com|
|google.co.in       |
|m.youtube          |
|youtube.com        |
```

I want to extract company name from the text
Output will be as follows

```
|Website            |Company|
|:------------------|:------|
|m.google.com       |google |
|uk.search.yahoo    |yahoo  |
|us.search.yahoo.com|yahoo  |
|google.co.in       |google |
|m.youtube          |youtube|
|youtube.com        |youtube|
```

Data is too big to do it manually and being a beginner, I tried all of the things I learned. Please help!

Comment: do you have a list of companies?

Answer (score 1):

Not bullet-proof but maybe a feasible heuristic:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Website': {0: 'm.google.com', 1: 'uk.search.yahoo', 2: 'us.search.yahoo.com', 3: 'google.co.in', 4: 'm.youtube', 5: 'youtube.com'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Website'].str.split('.').map(lambda l: [e for e in l if len(e)>3][-1])

0     google
1      yahoo
2      yahoo
3     google
4    youtube
5    youtube
Name: Website, dtype: object
```

**Explaination:**

Split string on `.`, filter out substrings with less than 3 characters, then take the rightmost element which wasn't filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

I applied this trick on a kaggle large dataset and it works for me. Assuming that you already have a dataframe object of Pandas named as **df**.

```
company = df['Website']

ext_list = ['www.','.com','.edu','.net','.org','.gov','.mil','m.','uk.search.','us.search.','.co.in','.af']
for extension in ext_list:
    company = company.str.replace(extension,'')

df['company'] = company
df['company'].head(15)
```

Now look at your data carefully either by looking at head or tail of data and try to find if there is any extension that you miss in the list if you find another then add it in ext_list.

Now you can also verify it using

```
df['company'].unique()
```

Comment: yeah! At first I tried the same thing but the data is too long. One or two iterations are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of checking the running time of it also its Big O Complexity would be O(n) so it also perfoms well on a large number of datasets.

```
import time

def time_it(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args,**kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(func.__name__ + " took "+ str((end-start)* 1000)+ " miliseconds")
        return result
    return wrapper

@time_it
def specific_word(col_name, ext_list):
    for extension in ext_list:
        col_name = col_name.str.replace(extension,'')
        
    return col_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    company = df['Website']
    extensions = ['www.','.com','.edu','.net','.org','.gov','.mil','m.','uk.search.','us.search.','.co.in','.af']
    result = specific_word(company, extensions)
    print(result.head())
```

[Here is I applied on estimate 10,000 values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNz0d.png)